# SPD 2010 Workflow Add permissions for list of users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm digging through my old workflows as I thought this is something I've done before....

In an SPD 2010 Workflow impersonation step, Add List Item Permissions, can't I feed it a semi-colon delimited list of user logins to assign permissions?

i've tried passing it

- `username1;username2;username3`,
- `username1@domain.com;username2@domain.com;username3@domain.com`,
- `domain\username1;domain\username2;domain\username3`

but none works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this has been reported by many in the past, and there really hasn't ever been introduced a solution to my knowledge.

Multiple users can still be assigned by using the list form (where the people picker functionality is available), but not the initiation form.

Comment: I'm not so good with the words.  :)   so are you saying the only way to do a multi user select is from a form where you would pick them all and then fire things off?  or what?

Comment: @Carp I think we are on the same page. [This blog post](https://nikpatel.net/2014/05/11/handy-sharepoint-designer-workflow-tip-configure-item-level-permissions/) shows what I mean - you can use the people picker (the window with the title "Select Users"), but you can't input multiple users with a separator such as `;`.